# Adjusting column of datagrid in WordPress using css

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a website product page layout as picture. Currently it show's 3 columns on desktop view and 1 column on mobile view. I need to customize the mobile view and make it view 2 columns.

[Picture of column in the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtPLT.jpg)

Can anyone help me? Here is my page link: [Carriz](https://carriz.my/search-cars/?min_price=1000&max_price=500000&ad_title=&cat_id=520&fbclid=IwAR3dpcJE3Xkw2MYkAAzOhx7GJgefOP5mw6DVdlDV8SAmLkCuet-0L8LAJgY)

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow (and in fact, all of the Stack Exchange Network) must be self-contained. The primary purpose of Stack Overflow is for questions to be useful to future visitors. Questions which require users to go off-site to get more information are not useful to future visitors, particularly once the off-site resource changes. This question might be good/useful, but you need to move enough code into the question so we know what you're asking without needing to go off-site to find out. Please see [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428) for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change col-xs-12 to col-xs-6 for this. or have to override the css by adding a specific class with style width:50% on mobile view
[image]

Comment: I could not find where to modify that col..when i resize the screen size, those value not changing, but the view in page changed.